# AppleScript Calendar automation

Tags: calendar, applescript, icloud

I have an AppleScript that runs on loop every two hours to modify a calendar B based on updates from another calendar A.

1. The script uses the on idle command below to wait 2 hours every loop. What happens if the computer stays idle for 1.5 hours then goes to sleep for 10 hours? Will there be 0.5 hours left when it wakes up? Any other scenarios?

> ```
>     on idle
>         my_code()
>         return (120 * minutes)
>     end idle
> ```

2. The script truly only needs to run if there is an update to calendar A, which is a shared iCloud calendar and can get updates from multiple people. The two hour loop is what I could figure out so far but I feel it is not efficient. Any more robust suggestions? Is there a way I can trigger the script to run only when it detects an update in calendar A? Or, along the same line of thought, is there a way to get the last timestamp the calendar was updated?

Thanks

Comment: Run the script via `osascript` and use [launchd](https://www.google.com/search?q=launchd+run+script) to schedule it.

Comment: please can you share the automator file or instructions? Is it triggered by Calendar alarm?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test following. Not sure it is the best way to solve your problem. Try yourself:

```
property oldStampDates : {}

on run
    tell application "Calendar" to tell calendar "Test Calendar" to set oldStampDates to get stamp date of events
end run

on idle
    --> Script retrieves last modified date and time of indicated calendar events.
    tell application "Calendar" to tell calendar "Test Calendar" to set newStampDates to get stamp date of events
    if newStampDates is not oldStampDates then display notification "The changes was detected"
    set oldStampDates to newStampDates
    return 30 -- seconds, default setting
end idle
```

NOTE: 1) you can put instead of display notification call to your handler my_code(), 2) you can put instead of 30 seconds other value, for example, return 10 (checking every 10 seconds).

Comment: I tested this script on my local calendar just now. At least on it the script works as expected, throwing notification on adding/removing/editing some event.